# javascript adjust function input variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

SO I am trying to adjust a function so that it can take different input when needed..

the function looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile() {
        var preview = document.querySelector('#<%=Image1.ClientID %>'); 
    }
</script>
```

and I want it to replace Image1 with an input in the function `previewFile(Image)`

Comment: You can pass it as an argument like previewFile(imageName)

Comment: `Image1` happens serverside, it's too late to change it clientside

Comment: Avinash after that how to pass it inside querySelector function?

Comment: adeneo so there is no way to build this tag inside querySelector somehow?

Comment: Sure there are ways to do this, for instance ajax, and I do believe there are certain workarounds in C# where you create dynamic javascript or something like that, but I don't really know C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this in your function pass entire **Object** with keyword **This**:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile(imageName) {

        var preview = imageName; 
        alert(preview);
   }
  </script>

<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" OnClientClick="previewFile(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile(imageName) {
        var preview = document.querySelector('#<%=' + imageName + '.ClientID %>'); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: I receive an error on the single quote.. they don't cove the part #<%=

Comment: this will never work as `#<%=Image1.ClientID %>` is generated server side.